# Second level caching is slower with memcache

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I enabled second level caching on entities with @Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE). I see cache hits when I am using the app, but benchmarking reveals that app is slower! How could this be? Is it the case because I did not cache all the associations?